# Line touching or in rectangle or circle

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, math, collision-detection

I want to find out if a line (with x1, y1, x2 and y2) is colliding with an object (if any part of the line is touching or within that object). The object may be a rectangle (with x, y, width and height) or a circle (with x, y and radius).

I would like two JavaScript code samples, each a function, one for line-rectangle collision `(lineX1,lineY1,lineX2,lineY2,rectangleX,rectangleY,rectangeWidth,rectangleHeight)` and the other for line-circle collision `(lineX1,lineY1,lineX2,lineY2,circleX,circleY,circleRadius)`.

The most efficient way of doing this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you could try to get the formula of all your shapes (If I remember, line = (ax+b), circle = (degree / 180 * Pi) with deb going from 0 to 360.

Comment: Don't you mean a line segment ?

Answer (score 1):

A line segment has the parametric equation

```
X = X0 + t (X1 - X0)
Y = Y0 + t (Y1 - Y0)
```

and a circle has the implicit equation

```
(X - Xc)² + (Y - Yc)² = R²
```

Substituting the first expressions in the last one gives you a quadratic equation in `t` which has

- no roots, then there is no intersection;
- one or two roots, which give you an interval of `t` inside the circle; you need to check intersection of this interval with `[0, 1]` to see if the segment has a portion inside.

For a line segment against an axis aligned rectangle, you can write the system of inequations

```
Xa <= X0 + t (X1 - X0) <= Xb
Ya <= Y0 + t (Y1 - Y0) <= Yb
```

If a coefficient of `t` is negative, you can swap `X0` <=> `X1` and `Xa` <=> `Xb` (same for `Y`) to make it positive.

Then the inequations become

```
(Xa - X0) / (X1 - X0) <= t <= (Xb - X0) / (X1 - X0)
(Ya - Y0) / (Y1 - Y0) <= t <= (Yb - Y0) / (Y1 - Y0)
```

to which you add the limits of the segment

```
0 <= t <= 1.
```

It is an easy matter to check if these bracketings are compatible.

For both circle and rectangle, you can start with a straight bounding box test.

Comment: The original question posits a line, not a line segment. In this case, does the interval [0,1] have any significance?

Comment: @this-vidor: I asked the OP clarification about this. In any case, my answer is "the most powerful" and one can just ignore the [0, 1] constraint.

Comment: To be honest, I don't understand any of that (take it as a compliment). I'm not sure what you mean to a line segment as opposed to a line. JavaScript code would be great (I have edited the question).

Comment: @Mirabilis: I am not a free coding facility.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I just don't understand.